# How to find device location in a timely manner

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, location-services

I am creating an app that needs to find the location of the local device and compare it to the location of another device. I am attempting to use the Google Play Services location apis to find the locations of the devices but it seems like it just takes way too long to connect. I haven't seen it connect yet. It is either really slow or something isn't setup correctly. Are these apis normally pretty quick when connecting?

Here is what I have:

```
public class LocationHandler implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{
    private Activity currActivity = null;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = null;

    public LocationHandler(Activity act)
    {
        currActivity = act;
    }

    public void Setup()
    {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null)
        {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(currActivity)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
    {
        Toast.makeText(currActivity, "Connected to service.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
    {

    }
}
```

I have the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I have also added this to the build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would use the LocationManager:

```
public class LocationHandler implements implements LocationListener{
LocationManager mLocationManager;

  public void Setup(){
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            500, 10, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //do something with your location
  }

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  }
}
```

This approach is straight forward and allows you to skip dealing with Google Play Services.

Comment: I have tried LocationManager and it never connected either. Do you know how quick it is usually? From what I read the GPS provider can take 1-3 minutes just to find a device and that is way too long. Haven't heard much better of the network provider either.

Comment: GPS Provider can take 1-3 minutes to warm up.  So if you have location disabled when you start your app and have to enable it and then wait.  If you have location set to GPS and it is turned on it picks up within a few seconds if you are in a place where you can get a GPS signal.  Are you using an actual device in a place where you can get a GPS location?  You could also try enabling all providers and use the device in High Accuracy Mode in stead of GPS in Settings.

Comment: So you are saying if the user has their location tracking on their phone already turned on then it will only take a second to locate them? Because I always have it on for my phone and I can't get it to connect. I will retry the implementation of the LocationManager and see what it does for me and I will update.

Comment: I am using my mobile device to test. I just set it to find the best provider. Hopefully that will help out.

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't seem to do anything. I never get a call back in any of the overriden methods. I have run another app that uses GPS to make sure it finds me and it seems fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: If you just use GPS_PROVIDER, try adding this line of code and see if you get a location object:

Location loc = 

mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 

Does that give you a location?

Comment: Ha yes that works! The overriden methods get called after that now too. I guess I just needed that. Awesome. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Great.  Glad it worked.  If you don't need to get updates after you get the location the first time you should call:

mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);